# Can't open SSMS - stating I don't have permissions

Tags: windows-7, permissions, sql-server, ssms

Whenever I try and run SSMS I get the following error.

> 'Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the approiate permissions to access the item. '

The dialog box has this path - `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe'`

I'm using Windows 7 Pro and I have two users setup, one is a limited account and the other full admin. It happens under both users, I have right-clicked and `'run as administrator'`. I have ticked the option in properties to always run as administrator. The path exists and I get the same error when opening the `.exe` from within the folder.

I have ran the latest Stinger release and it didn't pick up any viruses.

Anyone got any ideas what I can try next?

Comment: failing that, you may want to run Technet's filemon and try again to see what other files its loading. most likely the issue is caused by other files being accessed by SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume a repair or re-installing it doesn't help.

I've had similar issues and it was due to the ownership of the directory... For example, there is an account is called 'Dave', but the owner of the directory (C:\ProgramFiles) is 'Admin' and despite 'Dave' being an administrator, since he doesn't own it, he gets these *strange* behaviours.

Only do this if you know what you're doing (you can revert this back): Right click the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)` -> properties -> security -> advanced -> click the owner tab and change owner to TrustedInstaller or some one specific (like a name). Only do this if you know what you're doing.

Comment: I tried repairing it but can't a slightly different permissions issue. I'm going to give re-installing it a go.